# Validate required fields when traversing through each input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some dynamic generated html input controls. Some controls have required attribute. When I traverse through these fields I want to focus empty field and validate. But I want to avoid hidden field. I have to add only validate required attribute. Also want to avoid hidden field. this is the code I tried.

```js
$("input , select, textarea").each(function() {
     var element = $(this)
     if (element.val() == "")
           $(this).focus()
           return false
 });
```

Comment: To create a block of one or more instructions, like focusing an input control and exiting the `.each()` when one of the input controls is empty, you have to wrap those instructions in curly braces `{ }`.

Comment: can you please post the HTML code of at least one of your input fields?

Comment: Maybe change your selector to `input[required]:visible`?

Comment: Are any of your hidden fields "required"? because that's going to cause a whole other set of issues

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `attr` function to get the detailed of the `input` tag of your `HTML` for ex: `$(this).attr('hidden')` will return the value of the attribute of the current input tag.

Checkout the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwdg07L3/) for working example.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

Because of how validation works - specifically in Chrome, you need to bypass the normal validation of the form. To do this you need to set the attribute `novalidate` on the `form` tag and then supply custom validation to your `submit` event.

**why?**

Chrome, by default, will validate the form before submission - which is a cool idea - but unfortunately this process fails in practice because it does not allow for `hidden` elements to be in the form. In fact it throws an error ( *an invalid form control with name='' is not focusable* ). Without getting into what I personally think about this design flaw, it can be a frustrating hurdle that you don't know about until you run into it.

Secondarily there is sometimes an issue when submitting where fields that are both `required` and `hidden` can cause an error, or silently hold-up the form. To get around this you can remove the `required` attribute before submission, then re-apply to those elements after your custom validation.

---

### Example:

```js
$( "form" )
 .on( "submit", function( e ) {
 e.preventDefault();
 let hidden_required = [],
  invalid_form = false;
 $( "form" )
  .children( "input:text, select, textarea" )
  .each( function( i, ele ) {
  let prop = ele.tagName === "textarea" ? "textContent" : "value";
  if ( ele.required && ele[ prop ] == "" ) {
   if ( ele.classList.contains( "hidden" ) ) {
    ele.required = false;
    hidden_required.push( ele );
   } else {
    ele.focus();
    invalid_form = true;
   }
  }
 } );
 if ( !invalid_form ) {
  // do ajax submit
  alert( "valid form" );
 } else {
  // do alert or whatever
 }
 hidden_required.forEach( function( ele ) {
  ele.required = true;
 } );
 return false;
} );
```

```css
.hidden {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form novalidate>
<input /><br>
<input required /><br>
<textarea></textarea><br>
<input class="hidden" required>
<input class="hidden">
<input type="submit"  value="submit">
</form>
```